# What exactly does a Juniper PE use to find the correct transport LSP for the L2 circuit(Martini) neighbor?

Tags: juniper, l2vpn

Let's say, that I have a following simple L2 circuit(Martini) configuration:

```
root@PE4> show configuration protocols l2circuit
neighbor 192.168.2.2 {
    interface ge-0/0/5.777 {
        virtual-circuit-id 777;
    }
}

root@PE4>
```

This results with the following entry in the `l2circuit.0` table:

```
root@PE4> show route table l2circuit.0

l2circuit.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

192.168.2.2:CtrlWord:4:777:Local/96
                   *[L2CKT/7] 00:09:46, metric2 2
                    > to 172.22.213.2 via ge-0/0/3.0, label-switched-path PE4->PE2

root@PE4>
```

What table/database does Junos use to associate the `192.168.2.2:CtrlWord:4:777:Local/96` FEC with the RSVP-signaled `PE4->PE2` transport LSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `neighbor` statement implies the remote PE (which should be reachable via MPLS), so in short, `inet.3`.

I'm leaving the config out, but you'd see `Remote PE` in the output of `show l2circuit connections` as 192.168.2.2 in your case.

```
jhead@PE1> show l2circuit connections
Layer-2 Circuit Connections:

<...snip...>

Legend for interface status
Up -- operational
Dn -- down
Neighbor: 1.1.1.1
    Interface                 Type  St     Time last up          # Up trans
    ge-3/0/2.0(vc 1)          rmt   Up     Feb  5 18:30:57 2021           1
      Remote PE: 1.1.1.1, Negotiated control-word: Yes (Null)
      Incoming label: 300432, Outgoing label: 299824
      Negotiated PW status TLV: No
      Local interface: ge-3/0/2.0, Status: Up, Encapsulation: ETHERNET
        Description: to-PE2
      Flow Label Transmit: No, Flow Label Receive: No
```

Finally, the `inet.3` RSVP route toward the remote PE.

```
jhead@PE1> show route table inet.3 1.1.1.1

inet.3: 1253 destinations, 1560 routes (192 active, 0 holddown, 1239 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

1.1.1.1/32      *[RSVP/7/1] 1w1d 17:11:35, metric 5
                 > to 192.168.1.2 via ae1.0, label-switched-path PE1-to-PE2
                 [LDP/9] 14:28:32, metric 1
                 > to 192.168.1.2 via ae1.0, label-switched-path PE1-to-PE2
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that it's the `inet.3` table, but wasn't sure as I had understanding that `inet.3` is used strictly for resolving the BGP protocol next-hop addresses.